# Add menu item to another application

Tags: c#, vb.net, menu, reverse-engineering

gAlwaysIdle is a windows application which will add a menu item to Gtalk context menu.

[image]
<sub>(source: [tothepc.com](http://www.tothepc.com/pic/gtalkidle.jpg))</sub>

How can I do this to an application using vb.net or c#.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using .NET. gAlwaysIdle's website is down at the moment, but it most likely uses code/DLL injection to modify Google Talk's code at runtime and insert a menu item. This is only possible with native code (compiled) languages, which .NET languages aren't.

Edit: I found a download mirror and took a look at the application. It uses the SetWindowsHook method of DLL injection, which confirms my theory.